# How do I create an Advanced Search like in Image with multiple filters & Queries in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gitlab, jira, advanced-search

I'm trying to create an Advanced Search functionality which can take Multiple Queries at a time in React JS.
JIRA & GITLAB have similar functionality available. Please look at the images below.

[This is present on Atlassian JIRA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClAdb.jpg)

[This is present on GITLAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La4Gl.jpg)

Basic requirements:

- Single query will have 3 parameters viz., Title, Operator, Value
- There can be multiple such queries
- After selecting one parameter another dropdown will open up to select another parameter

Comment: SO is a platform. to share code / solutions. Not a "Do My Homework" thing. So please try to add some code / ideas, what you have tried and the effort which you have already done. Otherwise you will not receive any help here.

Comment: @KargWare that's what I did earlier. I even added my Code and explained what I did. Someone, told me that it was harder to understand and rather ask simpler things.

Comment: @KargWare  I have used MUI Select and added 3 such components. Which when selected the Title will display next Select Component which has Operator. And when Operator is selected it open next Select Component which will accept A Value. The help or guidance that I need here is if you see the picture you find that it is Textfield that has Drop Downs. So, using right Components is the question. Can you help?

Comment: Hey @HarshalPohare, I had exactly the same requirement & I've used a `react-filter-box` library, which is really a good library but has some open/ unmerged issues.